# iOS support for appium on windows

Tags: ios, windows, appium

I am trying to run my script on iPHONE 5 which is connected to my windows machine. I am getting below error:

> ERROR: debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
>   info: Configuring Safari session
>   ERROR: debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Safari","device":"iPhone 5s white"}}
>   info: Trying to use mobile safari, version 18
>   info: Looking for built in app MobileSafari
>   ERROR: error: xcode-select threw error Error: Command failed: 'xcode-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   ERROR: operable program or batch file.
>   ERROR: 
>   info: Got configuration error, not starting session
>   ERROR: error: Stderr: 'xcode-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   ERROR: operable program or batch file.
>   ERROR: 
>   ERROR: error: Stdout: 
>   ERROR: error: Could not prepare mobile safari with version '18': Error: xcode-select threw an error
>   ERROR: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: xcode-select threw an error
>   info: Cleaning up appium session
>   info: Error: xcode-select threw an error
>       at D:\QM_Work\AppiumForWindows-1.0.0\AppiumForWindows\node_modules\appium\lib\helpers.js:523:10
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
>   info: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: xcode-select threw an error)","origValue":"xcode-select threw an error"},"sessionId":null}
>   POST /wd/hub/session 500 1379ms - 204b

Comment: Well the error tell me appium is looking for Xcode, which is not available for windows. Looks like you can only use appium for iOS on OSX.

Comment: Any other work around to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to run the tests from a windows machine but not the way you are probably thinking. You will still need a mac. Here are the requirements:

A mac on your network with Appium server running
Has Appium environment installed properly
Has the .app on the machine
If you have these three reqirements fulfilled and there is no firewall blocking network access to the mac then you can do it. You will have to actual tests on the windows machine but instead of specifying 127.0.0.1:8080 in the setup method as the IP address of Appium server you will replace it with this: yourmacsipaddress:8080 and this should execute the test properly.

Remember that you have to specify the path of the .app in the test which is running from your windows machine. But the catch is that the path has to be the path of the .app in the mac and not on your windows machine.

So the tests will run from your Windows machine but the installation of the app, the automation, and the testing will be done on the mac but you will get the "pass" or "fail" update on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the doumenations of Appium you need OSX to test iOS:

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_25

Comment: http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest/index.html#requirements-and-support

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Windows for iOS testing because Appium requires Instruments and some other native, OSX-only libraries to tell the phone what to do. ([source](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_25))

Workarounds:

- look into a mac mini hosting service, where you can run your iOS tests on a virtual machine.
- buy a mac mini

Comment: http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest/index.html#requirements-and-support