# Is there a way how to run iOS, Android and WP Robot Framework tests using TeamCity on one server?

Tags: teamcity, appium, robotframework, python-appium

I have pretty straightforward question for you: is there a way how to run iOS, Android and WP Robot Framework test pack using TeamCity on one server?

Simply, I want to have one test codebase being run on one TC server and testing an app for all three platforms I count with.

Probably the biggest issue I can see is that I need macOS device to run the iOS appium. Could that be covered by some kind of virtual implementation?

Many thanks all in advance!

Comment: I don't see why not - Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I actualy thought that this might be the reason why: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774151/ios-support-for-appium-on-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774151/ios-support-for-appium-on-windows)

Comment: Like you suggested - Just make a VM within the same machine which is running iOS.