# Testing iOS application using Appium on Windows Machine

Tags: xcode, windows, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

Are there any possible solutions available for testing **iOS application using Appium on Windows machine**? Also I have to **reuse already created scripts for testing**. As I've developed Ruby test scripts with me, which I should be reusing for iOS testing from my windows machine.

I per my exploration, iOS testing has it's dependency on XCode, so you need Mac machine. Though there are some possible ways which I'm listing below with it's limitations, but they aren't applicable solution for me.

Explored Solutions:

**1. [Appium Studio](http://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/):**

Appium Studio Community version(Free) or Enterprise version(Paid) allows you to test the iOS as well as android application independent of the hardware or software. [ref: Appium Studio Docs](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TD/Appium+Studio)

But because of following **Limitations** I can't use Appium Studio:

- You can't import already created scripts in community edition. (I don't know about enterprise edition.)
- If you want to use eclipse for the editing the scripts, then you need an eclipse-plugin that bridges Appium Studio and Eclipse. But this plugin is paid one.

**2. Remote Server Functionality:**
This is a good option, but you need to have at least on Mac machine, which I'm not having. [How?](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-use-the-remote-server-functionality/311)

**Are there any open source alternatives available of Appium Studio ? 
Are there any other work arounds possible?**  I'm new to appium, any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer that makes the most sense found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836535/699665 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836535

Answer (score 2):

I found this [site](https://www.technonutty.com/2015/09/ios-simulator-windows-emulators-for-ios.html) and it does appear to be possible to run iOS simulators on a windows machine. As far as I can tell, Appium studio is able to start one of these simulators or it looks like you can use remote access.

https://docs.experitest.com/display/ES/Manual+Testing+Self-Training

If we can install one of the iOS simulators for windows and get that working then we can use [Appium's desktop inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop). It's free and open source. It offers the same element detection feature of Appium studio.

If we want to run the tests on a real device then we can use a cloud provider like Appium studio, [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/), or [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/)

Hope that helps

James