# What is the Recommended Approach to Automate IOS devices on Windows?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, seetest, experitest

I've seen this topic going around and the answers on each site and post have given it a wide range when talking about how to automate IOS devices from Windows PC.

One side, I've seen it where mainly the answer is: it's not possible due to Apple's rules, or its really messy to set up and not worth the effort to maintain, (though not explained in detail why its messy.) On the other side, I've read articles and posts about recommendations of IOS simulators such as iPadian, Smartface, etc; along with articles suggesting to stay from this software recommendations stating that they likely contain malware and viruses.

I've found other sources suggesting Experitest, Appium Studio, Quamotion,  TestProject to test and automate IOS on Windows PC. However, after reading the concerns of being cautious around these sites, and unable to proof if these studios/software legitimately support simulating real IOS environments on Windows and the arguments that are against going this approach, I can't tell which sources are reliable on this topic anymore.

The interest for me asking this question, as you can guess, is that I want to find a way to automate IOS on Windows and experience how run tests on iPhone.
I usually write my code in Eclipse Studio and use Oracle VM to create Android Emulators to test on. I'm fine if I need to have a physical IOS device in order to test.

All advice is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: The answer that makes the most sense to me is https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836535/699665

Answer (score 1):

The best option I would suggest to automate iOS app on Windows is to use cloud based solution like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com), [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com), etc.

This way you're sure that you will be using actual iOS device and the app would behave the same way as it would on real physical iOS device.

You can even inspect the app using Appium inspector and run the tests with ease as well.

The only drawback of using such solution is that most of them don't support latest version of Appium.

So the work around for this would be to setup [Microsoft Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/) pipeline on Mac OSX virtual machine and use latest Appium server version.

Answer (score 1):

The tools you mention - Experitest, Appium Studio, Quamotion,... all use the same approach: they communicate with real, physical iOS devices over a USB connection and then launch an agent (WebDriverAgent or similar) on the device which you can use to automate iOS devices.

They will usually require you to at least configure an iOS developer certificate and provisioning profile (much like you would when you are testing on a Mac).

Most of them also offer you a free trial and support, so you can go ahead and install the software and give it a try.